# @ng-select/ng-select show dropdown on typing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am using,
[ng-select](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
I am having one multi-select dropdown
everything working proper but i want some change, i want to show dropdown when user start types something and show only filtered data on user's typed content in text box.

Comment: Hi, it's seems working fine as you described as output result.

Comment: yes, i want to show dropdown only when users type something, right now its showing on focus

Comment: You meant to say, when you click on multi-select drop-down, it should not show the item list? Item list only displayed when you start a typing something. Am I correct?

Comment: yes,you got it.

Comment: something like autocomplete?

Comment: its better if you using multi select you should have checkbox to select all  and deselectAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below logic can helpful,

**.HTML**

```
<ng-select #elem [items]="cities2"
               bindLabel="name"
               bindValue="id"
               [multiple]="true"
               placeholder="Select cities"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCityIds"
               (open)="onOpen(elem)">
```

**.TS**

```
onOpen(elem){
 if(elem.filterInput.nativeElement.value == ""){
   elem.close();
 }
}
```

If you want to hide drop-down toggle ( V ), you need to add style in parent component/file.

**Index.html**

```
<style>
    .ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```